# DC Power supply stopped working properly

Tags: power-supply, troubleshooting

When I needed to set a maximum current I shorted the outputs and set the desired value with the current knobs. Now it doesn't work for some reason. Here's a short [video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLsMe.jpg). Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Nope, I'm not going to watch a video. Explain what you observe in words. Also provide a link to the manufacturer's users manual and specifications for the power supply.

Comment: Video is only 30 seconds, but okay. It's from Aliexpress, here's a [link](https://ru.aliexpress.com/item/32800389324.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.274233edRCiWnl). No user manual from what I understand. The displayed current value doesn't change when I turn the current knobs, but goes up a lot when I turn the voltage knobs.

Comment: Aliexpress link is in russian, so, that leaves us with only a nice picture of the supply. Maybe that chinese warning label gives a hint?

Comment: usually, the current adjustment function of power supplies like that has instructions associated with it, like set the open circuit voltage to 3V, then short the output,then adjust the current, then disconnect the probes, then adjust the voltage. Arbitrarily adjusting the voltage while the probes are shorted, I might imagine, can cause damage.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example from a printed manual I have on hand from a similar power supply:

[image]

Comment: Yes, sir, I did exactly like this instruction suggests. It worked before. Now on the step 5 I see no change on the current display. One thing I did wrong as you mentioned — I adjusted voltage when the outputs were shorted (played around with leds the other day). I guess, I damaged it. Any idea what might be damaged?